# How to prevent (If) statement from executing until a certain time has passed - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

so I'm fairly new to android application development but my fourth-year project requires a mobile application to be made so I have been working hard to learn! I've made the application beep once a certain value has been reached by using an If statement, but I need to prevent it from triggering accidentally. I want to make the loop have a set duration before it is able to be executed again, to prevent constant beeping.

I have looked into handlers but have had no success and just ended up breaking my code that was previously working. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
sensorFusion.eulerAngles().addRouteAsync(source -> source.stream((data, env) -> {
            // Put Yaw value form Euler Angles into A TextView
            final EulerAngles angle = data.value(EulerAngles.class);
            TextView kneeAngle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.kneeAngle);

            float yaw = angle.yaw();
            String yaw1 =String.valueOf(yaw);
            kneeAngle.setText("Yaw:  "+yaw1+ (char) 0x00B0);
            TextView repCount = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.repCount);
            String reps = String.valueOf(count);
            repCount.setText("Completed Reps "+count);



            //play beep when yaw a= Degree angle
            float a=90;
            double acceptedDiff = 0.5;

            if(abs(a-yaw) <acceptedDiff) {

                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.repbeep);
                mp.start();

                count = count +1;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the last time the application has beeped. Whenever a beep is  requested, check if a certain interval has passed since then.

```
public abstract class TimedBeeper {
    /** This makes the first beep always go through instantly. */
    private long lastBeep = 0;
    /** Interval in between beeps in milliseconds. */
    private long interval = 5_000;

    public void requestBeep() {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(lastBeep + interval < time) {
            lastBeep = time;
            beep();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void beep();
}
```

Note that this little example is **not** thread-safe.

The key to integrate this into your implementation is to identify the correct scope for `lastBeep`, hence which part of your program has to maintain it, so that it won't get reset in between multiple beep requests.

Comment: Thank you! It took me far longer to realize the problem but I eventually figured out how to do it. One thing i noticed is when you made the condition for (lastBeep + interval > time) it should be (lastBeep + interval < time). Once I caught that everything started working as Intended.

Comment: @AlecLaflamme Thanks for the notice, I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wait (some time) function - the easiest way
or use a function from some time librarian and write your method that will let you run if () after waiting for some time.
If this is not the answer you want, specify the question and I will try to help

Comment: Essentially I want the if statement that plays the beep to be ready to trigger on my value of 90 degrees, but then have to wait x milliseconds before a value of 90 triggers another beep. For example, if the sensor hits 90 degrees it beeps, but won't beep if I went passed 90 degrees and then briefly hit 90 again on the way back to a lower value. Thanks for the help thus far!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Izruo's feedback my code works and below for anyone else that may come across it. Note the only change form Izuro's code was the > should be < in the if the statement he mentioned. Also initiated last beep =0; right after my Fragments public class Fragment.

```
public class SensorFusionFragment extends SensorFragment {
private static final float SAMPLING_PERIOD = 1/25f;
private final ArrayList<Entry> x0 = new ArrayList<>(), x1 = new ArrayList<>(), x2 = new ArrayList<>(), x3 = new ArrayList<>();
private SensorFusionBosch sensorFusion;
private int srcIndex = 0;
double count=0; //for rep count loop
long lastBeep = 0;



            sensorFusion.eulerAngles().addRouteAsync(source -> 
            source.stream((data, env) -> {

            // Put Yaw value form Euler Angles into A TextView

            final EulerAngles angle = data.value(EulerAngles.class);
            TextView kneeAngle = (TextView) 
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.kneeAngle);

            float yaw = angle.yaw();
            String yaw1 =String.valueOf(yaw);
            kneeAngle.setText("Yaw:  "+yaw1+ (char) 0x00B0);
            TextView repCount = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.repCount);
            String reps = String.valueOf(count);
            repCount.setText("Completed Reps "+count);




             float a=90;
            double acceptedDiff = 0.2;
            long interval = 1000;
            long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            if ((lastBeep + interval < time)) {
                if (abs(a - yaw) < acceptedDiff) {

                    MediaPlayer beep = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.repbeep);
                    beep.start();
                    lastBeep = time;

                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }`
```